# Windows 10 start menu error green color appear above the content

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Windows 10 start menu error green color appear above the content of the start menu

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsd3z.png):

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: System REstore?

Comment: Some installed product is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem its from GeForce Experience [IN-GAME Overlay]

[The error from GeForce Experience IN-GAME Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqN53.png)